# angularjs $watch get index of changed array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, watch

i have an array that consists of multiple objects.

```
    $scope.userCompetences = [];
```

Now i have a deep watch on this array to check for changes:

```
    $scope.$watch('userCompetences', function (newVal, oldValue) {
    if(oldValue.length > 0)
    {
        var i = 0; // do something
    }
}, true);
```

Now my question is how can i get the index of the object in the array that has changed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to just call a function when this happens?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in userCompetences">
   <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" ng-change="change_function($index)"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel like this did not answer the question, although the person who asked the question decided that this would work for them. Assume that the data model has no link to a template, and that the person asking the question meant exactly what his question asked: "What is the best way to detect what has changed in an array from using $watch?"

Comment: The only reason to use $watch is when you want to $watch the $scope. The only reason to have a $scope is to have a template. When you want to see if an array has changed, you can use pure JavaScript.

Comment: I'll add that I tried with $watch for a while and failed. Then I found this answer and quickly got what I wanted and moved on.